# Difference between overloading Insertion operator and plus operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Both `>>` and `+` operators are binary operators. What does the difference in their syntaxes mean?

Why does `>>` have a return type (return by reference)? I know it is stupid but I am really confused between their syntaxes and would love a brief explanation.

```cpp
Sparse operator +(Sparse &s); //code for plus operator

friend istream & operator >>(istream &is,Sparse &s); //code for insertion operator
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading)

Comment: The first one is a member function, the second is a friend function, thus it has 2 arguments.

Answer (score 1):

`operator+` combines the data of two input objects (in your example, the left-hand object is `*this`) and returns a new object containing the combined data.

`operator>>` (and `operator<<`) returns a reference to the stream that is being acted on.  This allows for chaining multiple stream operations, eg:

```cpp
cin >> var1 >> var2 ...;
// which is the same as:
// cin.operator>>(var1).operator>>(var2) ...
// or:
// operator>>(operator>>(cin, var1), var2) ...
// etc, depending on the particular types and operator overloads being used

cout << var1 << var2 ...;
// which is the same as:
// cout.operator<<(var1).operator<<(var2) ...
// or:
// operator<<(operator<<(cout, var1), var2) ...
// etc, depending on the particular types and operator overloads being used
```

Without being able to chain, stream operations would have to be called individually instead, eg:

```cpp
cin >> var1;
cin >> var2;
...

cout << var1;
cout << var2;
...
```